# Is MongoDB is BASE database?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Is MongoDB is BASE database? many articles wrote that MongoDB  is acid database at document level but they not mentioned anything about that it base database or not, so I need to know about that if MongoDB is base database and support your answer with references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB as typical noSQL database is generally identified as BASE database , since from its earlier versions allow eventual consistency and it is ACID compliant only per single document , but since version 4.0 it support multidocument ACID transactions at replicaSet level , and since version 4.2 it support multidocumet ACID transactions at sharding cluster level.So developers can choose based on application and project requirements how to configure and use the database. Some more details from the vendor you can check [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions-in-mongodb)